# Searching the number of occurrences in a dynamically allocated array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, linear-search

> This is the method I am using to create the array.

```
int* createArray(int N)
{

    int* array = new int[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int rand_num = rand() % 10;
        array[i] = rand_num % 10;
    }

    return array;

}
```

> This is the method I am using to count the number of occurrences in an
>   array using linear search

```
    int linearSearch(int* nums, int N, int val)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
    {
        if (val == *nums)
        {
            count+=1;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

> This is the main method. The linear search method is returning 1 even
>   though there are two one's in the array. How can I solve this problem?

```
int main()

{

int N = 5;
    int* arr =  createArray(N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << *arr++ << " " << endl;
    }

    cout << linearSearch(arr, N, 1) << " " << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this for educational purposes, some course on pointers and searching algorithms?

Comment: One more mistake is that your loop is executing `N + 1` times inside the linear search. Make sure that you change that `i <= N` to `i < N`

Comment: Please note: Once an answer has been posted that points out an error in your code, you should not then fix that error - as this makes the answer invalid, even though it was posted 'in good faith'.

Comment: What's the point of `rand_num % 10;` after `int rand_num = rand() % 10;`? Please look at the modern functionalities provided by the `<random>` header or at least call `srand` in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

i think you don't increment your *nums in the function shearch.

so you always compare to array[0].

Comment: Did you correct the i<=N to i <N like @Arden Coder said on the top ?? can you edit your question with the new code you have please ??

Comment: yeah I did and I will

Comment: OMG ! I didn't saw but when you print in the main 'for' the pointer goes to the end of the array! so when you increment the pointer in the shearch fonction you go out of memory !

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three errors in your code! Two are in your `linearSearch` function, where (a) you don't increment the address being pointed to in the `if (val == *nums) {` line and (b) you go 'one beyond the end' of the array in the loop with `for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)` (the last element of an array of size `N` has an index `N-1`). Here is a fixed version:

```cpp
int linearSearch(int* nums, int N, int val)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (val == *nums++) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The third problem is, perhaps, more subtle. In your main code, you first assign the pointer `arr` the address returned by `createArray`, here:

```cpp
int* arr = createArray(N);
```

But then, in your output loop, you modify (increment) the value of that address:

```cpp
    cout << *arr++ << " " << endl;
```

So, when you later execute this line `linearSearch(arr, N, 1);`, the value of `arr` will be **wrong** - and you get undefined behaviour, trying to access invalid memory.

I would suggest using an *array index* in your output loop, like this:

```cpp
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " " << endl;
    }
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: I have edited the above code like you pointed out but the console is still outputting the wrong value

Comment: @Brian - **Please** don't keep editing your question when answers are posted!

Comment: @Brian - You need *all three* corrections - but make these in your 'local copy' of the code.

Comment: alright. do you have any other idea why it is outputting the wrong value?

Comment: @Brian On my PC, the code now gives `1 7 4 0 9 1` as its output - which is correct (there is only one 1 in the array - the last is the result of the search).

Comment: In my laptop its outputting 5 instead of one for some reason